# Error handling - convert #NUM to zero

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm writing a macro to cycle through a number of different spreadsheets that are in exactly the same format as each other. The source spreadsheets contain data in a table which occasionally contains the #NUM error (thanks to something going wrong in a different model!)

I have managed to account for all other error types, and some interesting formatting rules, using the below with a few other Case statements:

```
If IsNumeric(resultsarray(q,p) = false then

    Select case ResultsArray(q,p)

    Case IsError(ResultsArray(q, p))

                ResultsArray(q, p) = 0

    Case Left(ResultsArray(q, p), 2) = "0 "

                ResultsArray(q, p) = 0
```

Unfortunately #NUM doesn't seem to fall into IsError's purview. Does anyone out there know how I can simply overwrite the error with a zero/0?

Thanks in advance!!
Steph

Comment: Just use an if #num then 0 ...

Comment: Hi @SolarMike 
I have tried the if option and it leaves me with Error 2036 and Type Mismatch - which I am confused about as the array is defined as a Variant. 
Happy to take any other suggestions! Thanks.

Comment: Are you directly assigning the cell values to array? If you add watch on `resultsarray` then what do you see as the content on `#NUM` cell? Is it showing value `Error 2036`.

Answer (score 0):

This #NUM error occurs if the input is not a valid number. On your situation i suggets you to check whether the input is number or not instead of error check. This way you can check #NUM error as well.(Or you can do it both) With `IsNumeric(<input data here>)` you can do it. So just add one more case (`IsNumeric`) to your select case.

Comment: Heya, thanks for trying to help :) I have already used isnumeric and the field fails that test - I've now added this to my original post.The source of the error, in the original spreadsheet, is a formula which then saves everything as a (paste special) value ready for export. 

I know there must be something simple that I'm missing but for the life of me I can't see it!